# How can I train distilBERT more efficiently on my large text classification task?

Tags: python, performance, nlp, bert-language-model, distilbert

I've been thrown into the deep end a bit with a task at work. I need to use *DistilBERT* for a multi-class text classification problem, but here's the kicker the dataset is gigantic - we're talking **millions of samples!**

I've been messing around with it, and *DistilBERT* does seem to do the job well. However, training takes forever So, here are my dilemmas:

`Model Training`: How can I make *DistilBERT* handle this beast of a dataset more efficiently? Anyone got experience tweaking the training strategy, batch size, learning rate, etc.?
`Hardware Constraints`: Any hardware magic tricks to pull off? Is splurging on a fancy GPU the only way, or are there some tricks I don't know about?
`Inference Speed`: I also need to make sure the model can quickly classify new data after training. What are my options?

Any help would be a lifesaver!

Comment: on the hardware constraints - if you have a mac with with graphics card, you can try installing tensorflow-metal
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/